# Loading/rendering a new tile-based map to HTML5 canvas, replacing an old map

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas, html5-canvas

**Question summary**

[**JSFiddle code**](http://jsfiddle.net/gf66Ljpy/)

My `drawMap` function works correctly when called via `setUpGame`, but not when called via a button click. Can anyone else identify a problem based on my description below?

**Background**

I've got a set of tile maps for a HTML5 canvas game. I want to be able to clear the canvas and load new maps when the player walks off the edge of the canvas, but for now I'm [testing it using a button in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gf66Ljpy/).

My *code works correctly in the beginning* when my `setUpGame` function runs, which is self-evident from the map being visible. However, upon clicking the test button, the new map fails to load, despite using the same code as the `setUpGame` function. I'm pretty sure it's loading the map data itself, minus the graphic representation, but haven't figured out a good way to prove this, or what it would further imply about the error.

This is what I'm doing during the game setup, and subsequently when clicking the test button:

```
currentMap = room1; // manually assigning room 1 or 2
drawMap(currentMap);
```

Here is the drawMap function:

```
function drawMap(myMap) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myMap.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < myMap[i].length; j++) {
            if (myMap[i][j] === 0) {
                drawTile(0, 0, 32, 32); // grass
            }
            if (myMap[i][j] === 1) {
                drawTile(32, 0, 32, 32); // stone
            }
            if (myMap[i][j] === 2) {
                drawTile(64, 0, 32, 32); // water
            }
            if (myMap[i][j] === 3) {
                drawTile(96, 0, 32, 32); // sand
            }
            if (myMap[i][j] === 4) {
                drawTile(128, 0, 32, 32); // lava
            }
            mapLocationX += 32;
        }
        mapLocationX = 0;
        mapLocationY += 32;
    }
}
```

Here is the drawTile function:

```
function drawTile(imgStartX, imgStartY, imgEndX, imgEndY) {
    var tileImgSrc = allGameImages[0]; // map spritesheet
    BACKGROUND.drawImage(tileImgSrc, imgStartX, imgStartY, imgEndX, imgEndY, mapLocationX, mapLocationY, 32, 32);
}
```

**Previous research**

I've read up on the various stackoverflow questions involving tile-based maps and canvas, but most of them seem to cover problems rendering maps for the first time - my map works initially, so the solutions don't seem very relevant.

So far I have done a lot of testing (logging to console, placing deliberate errors) to see if I can pinpoint where the issue is coming from. At first I thought there was a problem with [how I choose which map should load next](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63537/improved-manipulation-of-a-2d-array-for-a-game-map), but that doesn't seem to be the case because the output results remain incorrect regardless of whether the value of `currentMap` is set to `room2` or `[[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]`.

(**A note on clearing the canvas:** when part of my larger game file, I would usually clear the 'BACKGROUND' canvas within the `drawMap` function. However for the purposes of my JSFiddle test I've left it commented out. I find it easier to 'visualise' the broken code output when the canvas retains the old map. Whether the canvas is cleared or not doesn't have an impact on the new map's failure to display.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reset mapLocationY=0 at the start of each new drawMap() or else your tiles are drawn below the canvas.

```
function drawMap(myMap) {
    mapLocationX = 0;
    mapLocationY = 0;
```